# Test angular 4 app with a global variable

Tags: angular

I have an angular app using a global variable set by an external .js library within ngOnInit(). Building and running works without any issue.
When running a test (with karma) I get the error "myglobal is not defined".

I tried defining the variable before describe(), like this:

```
var myglobal = { };
describe('AppComponent', () => {
```

That doesn't change anything. How I am supposed to define that variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to solve this you'll need to access the window object using `WindowRef` component

```
import {WindowRef} from './WindowRef';
```

and in the class

```
constructor(private winRef: WindowRef) {

console.log('Window object', winRef.nativeWindow['yourGlobalVar']);
//or  winRef.nativeWindow.yourGlobalVar
```

}

[source here](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/)

Comment: Creating a service solves the problem. It does not have to be a window, though (but using window could help if there are many globals). I used a "myglobalService" with a "get myglobal()". I was hoping I would not have to make my code heavier to add tests...